# How to uninstall OpenCV on MacOS?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv

I have two different version of openCV installed on my Mac. However I am unable to use openCV version 3.x.x in my program. It automatically takes version 4.x.x. How do I uninstall both versions? Where can I find openCV libraries on my Mac?

Comment: How did you install them? Are you using virtual environments or something similar?

Comment: I used pip3 install opencv-python to install it

Comment: For both versions?

Comment: yes another command I used was "brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD"

Comment: I assume you already tried `brew uninstall opencv3`? Did you also try to manually remove libraries and includes? Something like `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libopencv*` and `rm -rf /usr/local/include/opencv*`. For pip, use `python -m site` to figure out where the site-packages are and remove opencv from there (assuming `pip uninstall` didn't work). Worst case, install `locate` and search for libopencv* to figure out where any opencv libraries are left on your system.